# Flight delays for Europe

Tags: data-request, transportation, europe

From @RufusPollock (founder of [OKFN](https://okfn.org/)) on Twitter... ([link to tweet](https://twitter.com/rufuspollock/status/642384248360554496))

> **Anyone know if #EU has any #OpenData on flight delays like the US does?**

(Assuming he is referencing [US flight delays](http://apps.bts.gov/xml/ontimesummarystatistics/src/index.xml), from the [Bureau of Transportation and Statistics](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/))